# Issue with resolving HorneQ exception : Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null

Tags: java, jboss, hornetq

I have a JBoss server where a client must remotely connect to a JMS Queue so that it can send messages to it.

However, when running the client (run as part of an integration test using Arquillian), the following exception occurs when a connection is being made to the queue :

> javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory

```
at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:673)
at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:181)
```

> Caused by: HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
>       at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:946)
>       at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:669)

Is this a configuration issue with hornetq in my standalone.xml?

Client code:

```
final Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://jboss:4447");
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "User123_");

    final InitialContext context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);

    // Look up the connection factory
    final QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");

    // Look up the queue
    final Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("queue/testQueue");

    // Create a connection to the queue
    final QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection("user","User123_");

    // Create session from the connection
    final QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create a QueueSender
    final QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);

    final TextMessage msg = queueSession.createTextMessage();
    msg.setText("test");

    queueSender.send(msg);
```

The user is already configured on the JBoss server as an application user within the role "guest"

hornetq-server configuration from standalone.xml:

```
<hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>
            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>
            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>
            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>
            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="TestQueue">
                    <entry name="queue/testQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
```

Comment: What version of HornetQ are you running in JBoss AS and what version of the HornetQ client is the test using?  I've seen this kind of error before with a version mismatch.